# Hybris Remove Uniqueness of an existing attribute

Tags: xml, duplicates, sap-commerce-cloud

I am planning to remove the uniqueness of an attribute,

```
'name[unique=true]'
```

Planning to remove the unique=true so that data(name) that are the same wont be saved twice.

I tried to removed it from spring.xml file but it didn't work.
Anyone knows what are the other files to be modified?

How can I make the existing unique attribute to be 'non-unique'?

Comment: How did you try to remove that unique stuff and what **exactly** did not work?

Comment: `I tried to removed it from spring.xml file` - hopefully, you want to say `items.xml`, could you please elaborate your question more! For which itemType your want to remove it? what all steps you have tried?

Comment: I only removed the 'unique=true' from 'name[unique=true] in hot folder xml file.

Comment: How can I make the existing unique attribute to be 'non-unique'?

Answer (score 1):

Uniqueness is a property in the *-items.xml of your custom extension. I strongly encourage you to read the documentation about this file in the official [SAP Hybris documentation](https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8bffa9cc86691014bb70ac2d012708bc.html). Be careful that you shouldn't change uniqueness of Hybris' default attributes as I may have impact of the core system functionality.

You should see something similar to this. Please note the `unique="true"` modifier in the attribute.

```
<itemtype code="Product" autocreate="false" generate="false">
  <attributes>
    <attribute qualifier="myUniqueAttribute" type="java.lang.String">
      <persistence type="property" />
      <modifiers optional="false" initial="false" unique="true" />
    </attribute>
  </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

However, after making the change in the data model (extension-items.xml file), you should always run a system update. Be aware that some changes must be performed manually as for example, hybris never removes fields from the DB once created.

Is this change in one of your custom model, or in a hybris default one ?

(Edited after some refinement of the question in the comments)

Comment: i will try to run a system update.. will get back to you

Comment: When you specify a unique attribute ; Hybris creates an Index on the field in the database, with the unique value. Are you sure this one is properly removed as well ?

Comment: How can I make the existing unique attribute to be 'non-unique'?

Comment: hello all, thanks for the input. i've already resolved this issue thanks

Comment: Could you post your solution here ; so that community benefits from it ?